# What's the proper way to exit the application from WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnCreateMainForm()?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, error-handling, splash-screen

Let's assume something went wrong at [`WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnCreateMainForm()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.oncreatemainform(v=vs.110).aspx)'s time, how do I exit from application "gently"? I want to exit like use had hit the close button, so I guess [`Environment.Exit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx) will not fit well since it terminates an application immediately and might not allow the application to clean up itself.

My code look like this:

```
 public class MyApp : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
    {
        public MyApp()
        {
            this.IsSingleInstance = true;
        }

        protected override void OnCreateSplashScreen()
        {
            this.SplashScreen = new splashForm();
        }

        protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
        {
          if(!do_something()) {
            /* something got wrong, how do I exit application here? */
          }

          this.MainForm = new Form1(arg);
        }
```

And my `Main()` function:

```
[STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            new MyApp().Run(args);
         }
```

Comment: The application did not yet start.  It is still only initializing, the Application.Run() call happens later.  So Application.Exit() cannot work.  Sure, Environment.Exit() will get the job done easily.

Comment: Environment.Exit() will exit rather kill the application? if so, I guess it's the way to go

Answer (score 2):

I worked around this by creating an empty form which closes itself immediately in the load event handler. This allows to avoid the `NoStartupFormException`

```
    public partial class SelfClosingForm : Form
    {
        public SelfClosingForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SelfClosingForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
    {
        ...

        if (error)
        {
            //this is need to avoid the app hard crashing with NoStartupFormException
            this.MainForm = new SelfClosingForm();
            return;
        }               
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `return`:

```
protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
{
    if(!do_something())
    {
        return;
    }

    // This won't be executed if '!do_something()' is true.
    this.MainForm = new Form1(arg);
}
```

This will exit the current thread, so the `MainForm` property won't be set.

Comment: This doesn't exist gracefully, a NoStartupFormException is thrown.

Comment: Thank you for updating it @axk.